# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 28.6297543

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

Hi I am trying to send request (along with data) on a service, I am getting :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 28.6297543

By watching the exception i have understood that this is something to do with the Double type of attribute defined in my object, but frankly I have no idea how to correct this, here is my code base,

```
public String sendDataToServer(String IMEI, String mobileNo,double latitude, double longitude, String currentDateTime) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,WEBMETHOD);
        request.addProperty("IMEI",IMEI);
        request.addProperty("Mobile",mobileNo);
        request.addProperty("Lattitude",latitude);
        request.addProperty("Longitude",longitude);
        request.addProperty("CurrDate",currentDateTime);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope= new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION+WEBMETHOD,envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            responseText=response.toString();
        }catch (Exception e){
            responseText=e.toString();
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION : ===="+responseText);
        }
        return responseText;
    }
```

**Exception:**

> 09-14 23:19:25.497    7715-7891/com.appmap.appmap I/OpenGLRenderer﹕
>   Initialized EGL, version 1.4 09-14 23:19:25.535
>   7715-7891/com.appmap.appmap D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
>   09-14 23:19:25.964    7715-7973/com.appmap.appmap I/System.out﹕
>   EXCEPTION : ====java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize:
>   28.6288657 09-14 23:19:26.105    7715-7891/com.appmap.appmap V/RenderScript﹕ Application requested CPU execution 09-14 23:19:26.120
>   7715-7891/com.appmap.appmap V/RenderScript﹕ 0xb74204b8 Launching
>   thread(s), CPUs 4 09-14 23:19:27.689    7715-7913/com.appmap.appmap
>   I/b﹕ Received API Token:
>   AH0uPGFDNqYMrDR-8lmz9Mh9j0Qur4LRfiyR1LRZKIiDYe_RIucfdjJDgP0Q4xIsSYTz-jM_rY94NfXq7RqN3molPtWgF73yHQkcxrLLtPVZgs9YAAFw51uBUZignwrroaXN1gZ2v-IHt41x5dwRStsY7099cDXw8eCeAJr0Pnper8xHDYU8JbE
>   / Expires in: 432000000ms 09-14 23:19:27.689
>   7715-7913/com.appmap.appmap I/e﹕ Scheduling next attempt in 431700
>   seconds. 09-14 23:19:27.691    7715-7913/com.appmap.appmap I/g﹕ Saved
>   auth token 09-14 23:19:35.689    7715-7799/com.appmap.appmap D/Volley﹕
>   [9286] a.a: HTTP response for request=<[ ]
>   https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api 0x99e6744e NORMAL 2>
>   [lifetime=5545], [size=217949], [rc=200], [retryCount=0] 09-14
>   23:19:35.693s=maps_android_api&v=3&action=map_start_up&it=map_load.12088,on_create.2,on_resume.1,init.457&irt=12088,459,520,457 0x4d844933 NORMAL 10 09-14 23:19:47.318    7715-9435/com.appmap.appmap
>   I/System.out﹕ EXCEPTION : ====java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot
>   serialize: 28.6297543

Please help me handle this thing.

Comment: Please post the entire exception stack trace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Service Android Application : Cannot serialize 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586152/web-service-android-application-cannot-serialize-1-0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943475/ksoap2-in-android-cannot-serialize