# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: float

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

I have this function which is launched in a new thread. But I have the error in the float:

```
public void addProductServer(){

    String name = "sugar";
    float price = 70;
    String description = "good";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METODO_INSERT);
    request.addProperty("name", name);
    request.addProperty("price", price);
    request.addProperty("description", description);


    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        // In this Line belowe I get the error:
        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION_INSERT, envelope);
    } catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Integer result = 0;
    try {
        result = (Integer) envelope.getResponse();
        Log.i("Respuesta: ", result.toString());
    } catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
        soapFault.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And this is my error:

> jared.android.ulpgc.es.practica4_recuperacion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1269
>                                                                                                  Process: jared.android.ulpgc.es.practica4_recuperacion, PID: 27659
>                                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 70.0

```
jared.android.ulpgc.es.practica4_recuperacion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1269
                                                                                           Process: jared.android.ulpgc.es.practica4_recuperacion, PID: 27659
                                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 70.0
```

Please, I need some help!

Comment: Try changing your float to Float

Comment: Try using java.lang.Double

Comment: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586152/web-service-android-application-cannot-serialize-1-0 for help

Comment: can you try with request.addProperty("price", "" + price);

Comment: Using the MarshallFloat() class, It works!

Answer (score 0):

try to use 70f

```
float price = 70f;
```